# StoredProcedureQuery getResultList() does not return the data keys (column headers)

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, stored-procedures, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to get results from stored procedures on a Oracle database. These procedures are part of packages on the database, so I don't have visibility to the implementation of these procedures. So unless I execute the procedures with valid inputs, I don't have visibility to the returned column headers. I am using StoredProcedureQuery to execute these procedures in my code. The problem is, while mapping the result to POJO, I have to rely on the order of columns returned to map POJO fields.
I know one solution is to define the SQLResultSetMappings. But since I don't know what tables are queried for the results, I cannot map it to entities. Is there another method that returns the result with the column headers?
Here's my procedure declaration:

```
@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(
   name = "myStoredProcedure",
   procedureName = "MYUSER.PKG_MY_PACKAGE.MY_STORED_PROCEDURE",
   parameters = {
      @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, type = Long.class, name = "iMyNumber"),
      @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.OUT, type = Long.class, name = "oRetVal"),
      @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.OUT, type = String.class, name = "oRetTxt"),
      @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR, type = void.class, name = "oRetCsr"),
   }
)
```

And here's my DAO code:

```
public List<MyQueryResultModel> getMyQueryResults(Long myNum) {
  StoredProcedureQuery query = this.entityManager.createNamedStoredProcedureQuery("myStoredProcedure");
  query.setParameter("iMyNumber", myNum);
  try {
    List<Object[]> results = query.getResultList();
    List<MyQueryResultModel> myQueryResults = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Object[] result : results) {
      MyQueryResultModel myQueryResult = new MyQueryResultModel();
      myQueryResult.setId(objectToString(result[0]));
      myQueryResult.setName(objectToString(result[1]));
      myQueryResult.setDetails(objectToString(result[2]));
      myQueryResult.setAlias(objectToString(result[3]));
      myQueryResult.setDescription(objectToString(result[4]));
      myQueryResult.setAbbreviation(objectToString(result[6]));

      myQueryResults.add(myQueryResult);
    }
    return myQueryResults;
  } catch (Exception e) {
    return null;
  } finally {
    query.unwrap(ProcedureOutputs.class).release();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `resultClasses = { MyQueryResultModel.class },` that will handle the object mapping by itself as long as your class is an `@Entity`, [example](https://howtodoinjava.com/hibernate/jpa-21-namedstoredprocedurequery-annotation-example/).

If not you could use `resultSetMapping` passing your `SQLResultMapping` here is an example of the [usage](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-sql-resultset-mapping), I don't believe you need to know the tables that the query will hit in advance, you just need to know the column names, which can be defined in your SQL query. if not you could use an alias in your last statement to define them.

Answer (score 0):

@StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR, type = void.class, name = "oRetCsr"),

This is Oracle stored procedure. So You can run this in Toad or PL/SQL  query run and see all output column in resultset.Then use those column names in resultset
Example has   System.out.println (rset.getString ("ENAME")); to get ENAME from cursor
SO map your in type Out type parameter and check refcursor for data and from columname you can get data.

How to pass parameters to Procedures and Functions in PL/SQL?
In PL/SQL, we can pass parameters to procedures and functions in three ways.

1) IN type parameter: These types of parameters are used to send values to stored procedures. 
2) OUT type parameter: These types of parameters are used to get values from stored procedures. This is similar to a return type in functions.
3) IN OUT parameter: These types of parameters are used to send values and get values from stored procedures.

When you run in toad you should be able to create output class
   package demo;

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedStoredProcedureQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedStoredProcedureQuery;
import javax.persistence.ParameterMode;
import javax.persistence.StoredProcedureParameter;

@NamedStoredProcedureQueries({ //
@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(name = "Role.findRolesViaProcedure", procedureName = "collect_roles",
        resultClasses = Role.class, parameters = { //
        @StoredProcedureParameter(name = "role_list_o", mode = ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR, type = void.class) }) //
})
@Entity
public class Role {

    @Id @GeneratedValue//
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}


 RoleRepository.java
package demo;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.Procedure;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

interface RoleRepository extends CrudRepository<Role, Serializable> {

    @Procedure
    List<Role> findRolesViaProcedure();
}
 schema.sql
CREATE TABLE "ROLE" 
   (    "ID" NUMBER(10,0), 
    "NAME" VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)
   );

Insert into TRAINING.ROLE (ID,NAME) values ('1','A');
Insert into TRAINING.ROLE (ID,NAME) values ('2','B');
Insert into TRAINING.ROLE (ID,NAME) values ('3','C');


CREATE or replace PROCEDURE collect_roles (role_list_o OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) AS
     BEGIN 
       OPEN role_list_o FOR SELECT id, name FROM role; 
     END;

 SpringDataJpaBugDatajpa652Application.java
package demo;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.Database;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringDataJpaBugDatajpa652Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringDataJpaBugDatajpa652Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean bean) {
        return bean.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean(DataSource dataSource) {

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean bean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

        bean.setLoadTimeWeaver(new org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver());
        bean.setDataSource(dataSource);
        EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter jva = new EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter();
        jva.setDatabase(Database.ORACLE);
        jva.setShowSql(true);
        bean.setJpaVendorAdapter(jva);

        return bean;
    }
}
 SpringDataJpaBugDatajpa652ApplicationTests.java
package demo;

import java.util.List;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = SpringDataJpaBugDatajpa652Application.class)
public class SpringDataJpaBugDatajpa652ApplicationTests {

    @Autowired DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired RoleRepository roleRepository;

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {

        System.out.println(dataSource);

        List<Role> roles = roleRepository.findRolesViaProcedure();

        System.out.println(roles);
    }
}
```

https://gist.github.com/thomasdarimont/129bc15d0ccc459610c2